# How to set grpc response in json list

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, grpc-python

I have this `grpc` response:

```
elem {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
elem {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
```

I want to make it as

```
[
  {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
  {'a': 5, 'b': 10}
]
```

How to do it in my flask project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this response object to get the object list:

```
message Response{
  repeated Element elem = 1;
}
message Element {
  int32 a = 1;
  int32 b = 2;
}
```